# Random org.json.JSONException: Unterminated array at character 24367

Tags: java, php, android, json

Android 4.2.2
I'm parsing a JSON string sent from PHP server. Parsing the same string gives this exception on **random** character number each time. **Sometimes** it's loaded successfully. The size of the input is 202858 bytes. I can't post it here as it's private data but I guess it's correctly formatted. If I run my app in debug/step-by-step mode it loads all the time! Also if the size of the response is smaller (fewer lines but not sure how many exactly) it also loads all the time.

Here is how I load the stream:

```
        String JSONResp = "";

        try {
            URL u = new URL(params[1]);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod(params[0]);
            conn.connect();

            /* Here is the new code. This works! */
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"), 4096);
            StringBuilder  sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;
            while( (line = br.readLine()) != null ) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            JSONResp = sb.toString();


            /* Old code starts here. This is not working!
            // Read the stream
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            byte[] b = new byte[4096];
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            while ( is.read(b) != -1) {
                baos.write(b);
            }

            JSONResp = new String(baos.toByteArray());
            */

            JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(JSONResp);

            //TODO read result form the input stream
            _HTTP_code = 200;

            return arr;
        }
        catch(Throwable t) {
            _HTTP_code = ERROR_Throwable;
            _HTTP_text = "Error";
            _HTTP_body = "Could not parse response!";

            Log.e("JSON", "JSONResp.length() = " + JSONResp.length() + ".");
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The code is executed from a separate thread and this is what I found in the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html):

> Instances of this class are not thread safe. Although this class is nonfinal, it was not designed for inheritance and should not be subclassed. In particular, self-use by overridable methods is not specified. See Effective Java Item 17, "Design and Document or inheritance or else prohibit it" for further information.

I'm not sure if I understand that text correctly but I don't have more than one thread querying the server at the same time.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It looks to me like the JSON is malformed.

Comment: No it's not. I actually get it working by rewriting the code reading from the input stream. I updated my initial post.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class GetResultTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {  
Activity act;
private ProgressDialog pd;
private boolean isInternetConnected = true;

public GetResultTask(Activity _act){
    this.act = _act;
    pd = ProgressDialog.show(act, null, "Loading...", true );
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {

}

protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    pd.dismiss();
    if(!isInternetConnected){
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Check your Network Connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("option", "getPeople"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("val", params[0]));

    String downloadedString = null;
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://example.com/filename.php");

    try {
        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        UrlEncodedFormEntity ent = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,HTTP.UTF_8);
        httppost.setEntity(ent);
        //new
        //HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httppost);
        //System.out.println("Response");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        //System.out.println("Response is :-\n"+response);

        InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
        StringBuilder stringbuilder = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader bfrd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String line;
        while((line = bfrd.readLine()) != null)
            stringbuilder.append(line);
        //string returned as JSON
        downloadedString = stringbuilder.toString();
    } 
    catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(UnknownHostException e){
        isInternetConnected = false;

    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //System.out.println(downloadedString);
    return downloadedString;

}   
 }
```

Comment: Try this above AsyncTask. You can also check your JSON if its valid or not at jsonlint.com